# Unity превращение transform.rotation в Vector2

Tags: c#, unity3d

Когда игрок входит в триггер, идёт проверка на булл, в зависимости от которого, задаётся новый вектор. Сейчас понял, что это можно оптимизировать, но мозга не хватает понять как.
Как, к примеру, сделать, что бы при входе игрока в коллайдер, задавался вектор в зависимости от поворота коллайдера?

```
        if(DashDR == true)
        {
            PlayerController.dashTime = PlayerController.dashStartTime;
            PlayerController.physics = 1;
            PlayerController.X = 1;
            PlayerController.Y = -1;
        }
        if(DashDL == true)
        {
            PlayerController.dashTime = PlayerController.dashStartTime;
            PlayerController.physics = 1;
            PlayerController.X = -1;
            PlayerController.Y = -1;
        }
```

Comment: Объясните нормально чего вы хотите. Из вопроса не очень понятно. Если вы хотели чтобы вектор указывал вперед просто умножьте Quaternion вращения на требуемый вектор, это приведет к повороту. `transform.rotation * Vector3.forward`

Comment: Сложно объяснять то, что сам не очень понимаешь, но да, это именно то, что нужно)

Comment: у вас вопрос написан без объяснений причино-следственных связей. Надо догадываться какой коллайдер куда повернут, причем тут тригер, а код так вообще не понятно что тут к чему